# Fast report - printing lines to fill empty space on the bottom of the page between masterdata and pagefooter bands

Tags: fastreport

My masterdata band has stretched property set to True.
In masterdata band every field has vertical frame lines.

If amount of records is several pages or longer, I want at the end of each page if another record can not fit on the same page that free space between masterdata band and pagefooter band to have lines stretching to the pagefooter.

In order to that I have child band "ChildFrameLines" which purpose is to draw those frame lines and fill the empty space until the page footer.

```
procedure MasterData1OnAfterPrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
  if Engine.Freespace < MasterData1.Height then
    Engine.Showband(ChildFrameLines);
end;
```

This code does the job except in one case.

Let's say the last record on the page (10th data record) didn't have need to strech
and the first record on next page (11th data record) requires the master data band to stretch itself to show all the data.

What happens is that after the report prints the last record on the page it goes to MasterData1OnAfterPrint event and checks whether to showband ChildFrameLines.

It says that masterdata1.height (of the 10th record) is bigger then Engine.Freespace
and it does not show ChildFrameLines. Since the 11th record is strecthing masterdata band it goes to the next page and ChildFrameLines was not called when it should of been.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Your solution put me in the right track, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use two-pass report. Store height of each TfrxMasterData in the TfrxMasterData.OnAfterCalcHeight event in the array on the first pass and then use stored values on the second pass

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I resolved it using a method similar that the one outlined in your question, but using another event.

The problem with the original solution was that you are using `OnAfterPrint` to compare the height of the master band, but in that event the height you get is the height of the *next* row, not the current one. Your solution may appear to work if all the rows have the same height, but fails with rows of different height.

I changed it to the do the processing in the `AfterCalcHeight`, in which `MasterData1.Height` still has the height of the current row. Also, I need to fill the last page too, so I do that checking for the last record of the band in `AfterPrint` (`DoublePass` needs to be enabled for this).

Here is the code that I used:

```
var
  RecordCount: Integer = 0;

procedure MasterData1OnAfterCalcHeight(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
  // if the free space is less than the height of the current row of MasterData1 the
  // engine is going to generate a new page, so we show the child band before that
  if Engine.Freespace<MasterData1.Height then begin
    // this is one of the memos with the lines, the rest of memos have
    // StrechMode set to MaxHeight and the child band has Stretched set to True
    MemoChildFrameLines.Height:=Engine.Freespace;
    ChildFrameLines.Visible:=true;
    Engine.ShowBand(ChildFrameLines); // show the band at the current position
    ChildFrameLines.Visible:=false; // hides the band for the next record
  end;
end;

procedure MasterData1OnAfterPrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
  // DoublePass needs to be enabled so we can count the records in the first pass
  if not Engine.FinalPass then begin
    RecordCount:=RecordCount+1;
  end
  else if (<Line>=RecordCount) then begin // last record of the master data band
     MemoChildFrameLines.Height:=Engine.Freespace; // filling remaining space
     ChildFrameLines.Visible:=true;
  end;
end;

begin
  ChildFrameLines.Visible:=false; // hiding the band by default, only shown when needed
end.
```